# matrix A 2 x 2 with one eigen value is similar to a diagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

prove or provide a counter exaple :

1. $$\ A ∈ M2×2 (R)$$ with one eigen value $$\lambda$$ is similar to \begin{pmatrix}\lambda &0\\ \:0&\lambda \:\end{pmatrix} or \begin{pmatrix}\lambda &1\\ \:0&\lambda \:\end{pmatrix}

2.If  $$\ n = 3, rankA = 1$$ and $$2020$$ is an eigenvalue of A, then for every $$ 0 \ne v ∈ R^3 $$
is an eigenvector
of A.

I'm new to the forum so it is a  bit difficult for me with the mathJAX . the first question I saw someone already uploaded it but no one responed ( 2 years ago ) .
I cant come up to a decision for both questions hope someone can lead me . thank in advances!

Answer (score 0):

For (1), use Jordan canonical form.

For (2), try the most obvious $3 \times 3$ matrix of rank $1$ with an eigenvalue of $2020$.

EDIT: Here's how to do (1) without knowing Jordan canonical form.
There are two cases, depending on whether there are two linearly independent eigenvectors.  If there are, the matrix is in fact $\lambda I$.  If not, note that $(A - \lambda I)^2 = 0$, and take a basis $u_1, u_2$ where $u_2 = (A - \lambda I) u_1 \ne 0$.

Comment: I haven't learned Jordan canonical form ...